# Switch to failover IP instead of main IP for all HTML requests?

Tags: networking, centos, failover, centos8

I'm using Centos 8 and with my luck, my main IP is blacklisted on an API I'm trying to use.

I have 3 failover IP addresses however. Is it possible for me to use one of these failovers instead?

Comment: How are you making the request to the API?

Comment: @TomH I'm using Python. It's just a basic HTML GET for getting a JSON file

Comment: I think you would have to update your route table to prefer the other IP address.